# How to write the code if the direction is opposite of the other?

Tags: java, enums

I have an enum class called Direction which has objects `S, N, W, E, and none` (South, norht, east, west and none). And I have a method `public boolean isOpposite(Direction other)` which should report if the given direction is opposite of the other. none is never opposite anything else, but N / S are opposites and E / W are opposites. So, how can I check in boolean if the direction is the opposite of the passed object?

```
public enum Direction {

    N, E, S, W, none;

    public Direction cycle()
    {
        if (this.equals(Direction.N))
            return Direction.E;
        else if(this.equals(Direction.E))
            return Direction.S;
        else if(this.equals(Direction.S))
            return Direction.W;
        else if(this.equals(Direction.W))
            return Direction.N;
        else if(this.equals(Direction.none))
            return none;

        return null;
    }

    public Direction getOpposite()
    {
        if(this.equals(Direction.N))
            return Direction.S;
        else if(this.equals(Direction.S))
            return Direction.N;
        else if(this.equals(Direction.E))
            return Direction.W;
        else if(this.equals(Direction.W))
            return Direction.E;
        else if(this.equals(Direction.none))
            return Direction.none;

        return null;
    }

    public boolean isOpposite(Direction other)
    {
        //???
    }

}
```

Comment: Have you tried anything?

Comment: Wow, already a vote down.. yeah I've edited the code and I'm having difficulties with coming up with the right approach towards the method isOpposite()..@IsmailBadawi

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
return getOpposite() == other;
```

Comment: Could you please clarify your answer ?

Comment: @joshua You've done the hard work yourself in the `getOpposite` method. All you have to do to check if `this` is opposite to `other` is check if `this.getOpposite()` is the same as `other`.

Comment: THanks for the quick reply, so, for example, getOpposite() == other is similar to N == N or S ==S ??

Comment: Yes. By the way, you don't need to use `.equals()` for enums, so you can simplify your own code by using `==`.